# zend_json an array that contains objects

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, object, encoding

so suppose I have this

```
$arr = array(some object with property a,b,c,d,etc);
```

and you call `Zend_Json::encode($arr);`

instead of encoding the object within it as well, it will just return an encoded empty array: `[{}]`

which is an epic fail

how do I tell Zend_Json to also encode the object within the array and not just return this failure

##################### **EDIT**

alright so I actually have this method in the class:

```
public function toJson(){
    $params = get_object_vars($this);
    return Zend_Json::encode($params);
}
```

yet it's still only outputting an empty array

[{}]

encoding the object itself works, but not if it's inside an array

...

Comment: Are they protected or private properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you are encoding PHP objects by default the encoding mechanism can
>   only access public properties of these objects. When a method toJson()
>   is implemented on an object to encode, Zend_Json calls this method and
>   expects the object to return a JSON representation of its internal
>   state.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.advanced.html#zend.json.advanced.objects2

Update : This is the piece of code I tried. And it works fine, I feel your object properties has no values.

```
class Hello 
{
    private $hello = 'Hello';
    public $wolrd = ' World';

    public function getProperties()
    {
            return get_object_vars($this);
    }

}
$json = new Zend_Json();
$hello = new Hello();
echo $json->encode( array( $hello->getProperties() ) );
```

Result :

```
[{"hello":"Hello","wolrd":" World"}]
```

Hope fully this will work. Some thoughts from the post ;) http://blog.calevans.com/2008/02/21/zend_jsonencode-and-wth-are-all-my-properties/

Comment: +1, a simple implementation of toJson can just simply create a new stdClass, copy the value of non-public properties to this object and then return `Zend_Json::encode(myValueObject);`

Answer (score 0):

By default Zend_Json::encode method uses PHP json_encode function. You need to set Zend_Json::$useBuiltinEncoderDecoder to true and implement a toJson method in your domain object which is in your array. This method should return valid json string.

```
class Foo
{
    private $a;
    private $b;

    public function toJson()
    {
        return $json = Zend_Json::encode(array(
            'a' => $this->a;
            'b' => $this->b
        ));
    }
}
Zend_Json::$useBuiltinEncoderDecoder = true;
echo Zend_Json::encode(array(new Foo()));
```